# ERROR: extra data after last expected column (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, copy

I want to write in the table "genome1 "in which there is one column of "shingle" (VARCHAR 64), all data from the text file. 
In data are written in a look: FA, GL, YH, LO, GH, KL, HF...
In case of execution of the command of COPY:

```
COPY genome1(shingle) FROM '/path/to/file/genome1.2.txt' (DELIMITER (','));
```

There is an error:

> ERROR: extra data after last expected column

Changeover of a command on:

```
COPY genome1(shingle) FROM '/path/to/file/genome1.2.txt' CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';
```

Gives nothing (COPY 0). Please help, I do not understand in what a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood how to correct this problem. Postgres did not allow to copy as there was no transfer sinks. It was necessary to enter input data in a format:

```
AA 
DD
FF
...
```